# Migration where the data prevents the change

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I know you are not supposed to manipulate data inside your migration.

However, I need to make a column nullable with unique values, but at the moment it does have duplicate values (currently kinda placeholders), which would break the migration.

This is my (Laravel) migration:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('user_subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('cc_auth_code', 50)->comment('Approval Code')->change();
        $table->string('guid', 100)
            ->comment('Transaction ID')->nullable()->default(null)->change();
    });

    // for some reason this does not work inside the callback
    UserSubscription::whereGuid('UNKNOWN_GUID')->update(['guid' => null]);

    Schema::table('user_subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unique('guid');
    });
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is your error on the update row?

Comment: You mean if I run the update inside the closure? It simply doesn't work nd so I get the "duplicate key" error when trying to create the unique index.

Comment: But this is not the point of my question. I'm wondering if modifying the data inside the migration is the right way or if there is another way. I haven't found any discussion online.